# Find column two entires share MySQL

Tags: mysql

So I have a table called users_chat_rooms:

```
mysql> describe users_chat_rooms;
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field   | Type             | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id      | int(11) unsigned | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| user_id | int(11)          | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
| chat_id | int(11) unsigned | NO   | MUL | NULL    |                |
+---------+------------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

I have two users who have unique user_id's and I am trying to figure out how to find out if/what chat_id's they have in common.

Thanks!

Comment: Can you show us what you've done so far?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

query like this should do the trick:

```
select chat_id
from users_chat_rooms
where user_id in (#USERID1#, #USERID2#)
group by chat_id
having count(distinct user_id) = 2
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks! Very straightforward and easy to understand!

Answer (score 2):

I'd join like this:

```
select ucr1.chat_id from users_chat_room ucr1 
inner join users_chat_room ucr2 on ucr1.chat_id = ucr2.chat_id
where ucr1.user_id = :userid1 and ucr2.user_id = :userid2
```

Comment: this works perfectly but I found the other solution simpler. Thanks!